# Zend framework 2: контроллеры

Tags: zend-framework-2, php

Как контроллер узнает, какой шаблон ему грузить? Или нет, по-другому. Если в контроллере не указывать какой конкретно шаблон нужно загрузить, то как в этом случае контроллер узнает какой шаблон ему грузить?

Answer (score 1):

Загружается соответсвующий контроллеру и действуию(action) шаблон.
Например, если модуль = site, controller = siteController, a действие = edit, тогда загрузится шаблон wiew\site\site\edit.phtml